# how to prove n-th root of limit of f(x) is limit of n-th root of f(x)

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to know the exact proof. 
if $ \lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L $

$ \lim_{x \to a} \{f(x)\}^{1/n} = L^{1/n} $

most of books tell that it is special case of n squares, but I couldn't understand.

Comment: An "exact proof" will depend on what other things about limits you have already proved and so can use. Please edit the question to start your proof using what you're allowed and tell us where you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma:**

Let $a\geq 0, b \geq 0$. Then we have
$$ |a^{\frac{1}{n}}-b^{\frac{1}{n}}|\leq |a-b|^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

**Proof**

Suppose $a\geq b$ , define $c=a^{\frac{1}{n}}$ e $d=b^{\frac{1}{n}}$, so $c-d \geq 0$ by  binomial expansion we have
$$c^{n}=((c-d)+d)^{n}=\sum^{n}_{k=0}{n \choose k}(c-d)^k d^{n-k}\geq d^n +(c-d)^n \geq 0 $$

so $c^n-d^n\geq (c-d)^n \geq 0$, and then
$$|a-b|\geq |a^{\frac{1}{n}}-b^{\frac{1}{n}}|^{n} $$
so $$|a^{\frac{1}{n}}-b^{\frac{1}{n}}|\leq |a-b|^{\frac{1}{n}}. $$

**Theorem:**

If $ f(x) \geq 0$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)=L$ then $\lim\limits_{x \to a} (f(x))^{\frac{1}{p}}=L^{\frac{1}{p}}$, $p \in N$.

**Proof:**

We have that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)=L$ then $\forall \varepsilon^p >0$ we can take $\delta>0$, so that $|x-a|< \delta$ implies $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon^p$. From this we have $|f(x)-L|^{\frac{1}{p}}<\varepsilon$,  and from the previous inequality (lemma) follows
$$ |f(x)^{\frac{1}{p}}-L^{\frac{1}{p}}|\leq |f(x)-L|^{\frac{1}{p}}<\varepsilon$$
then by definition of limit we conclude $\lim\limits_{x \to a} (f(x))^{\frac{1}{p}}=L^{\frac{1}{p}}$.